# There is no default constuctor avalible in ...

Tags: java

Ошибка при наследовании конструкторов.

```
 public EqAudioVisualizer() {
    eqVisualizer = new Visualizer(0);
    eqVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
    setupVisualizer(eqVisualizer);
    setter();
    }
```

Компилятор говорит "there is no default constuctor avalible in bla bla

Создал дочерний класс, при этом не получается в нем переопределить конструктор.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

а bla bla - это случайно не предок вашего класса? Ошибка означает, что у предка вашего класса нет конструктора без параметров. Поэтому вам в своем конструкторе надо явно вызвать один из конструкторов предка.

Comment: Спасибо! Уже разобрался, но проблема была именно в этом.